# change mixin depending on media query

Tags: sass

I would like to change a @mixin variable depending on the viewport size. I taught that I could do it like this:

```
@mixin site-wrapper {
    width:96%;
    padding:2%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    @mixin site-wrapper {
        max-width:$size__site-wrapper;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
}
```

But that did not seemed to work. Is this doable in some similar way?

Comment: It's not clear what your actual goal is here.  Why do you want such a mixin?

Comment: Because of the responsiveness of the site. If the viewport is too large I want this mixin to have a fixed width, if not it should fill the with of the site. This mixin is then used in the content wrapping divs, which has independent settings as well.

Comment: I understand what media queries are for.  It is unclear why you need a mixin for this, since you should theoretically only have 1 such element.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if I just change the order of the media query and the mixin it works, like this:

```
@mixin site-wrapper {
    width:96%;
    padding:2%;
    @media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
        max-width:$size__site-wrapper;
        margin:0 auto;
   }
}
```